# Resolving Error C2399 in Visual C++

Tags: c++

When I execute any C++ program in Visual Studio, event the simplest like the following:

```
class base
{
public:
    int i[10];
};

int main()
{
    base p1;
    std::cout << sizeof(base);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

> Error C2399   variable templates are not supported in this release.
>   Error C2061   syntax error: identifier '__make_integer_seq'.
>
> Error C2065   '_Vals': undeclared identifier.
>
> Error C2975   '_Vals': invalid template argument for
>   'std::integer_sequence', expected compile-time constant expression
>
> Error C2061   syntax error: identifier 'make_integer_sequence'
>
> Error C2631   'identity': a class or enum cannot be defined in an alias
>   template
>
> Error C1903   unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping
>   compilation

How can I resolve the above errors ?

Comment: The code you provided does not match the errors you are showing.  Have you done a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have extra cpp files in the project that the compiler is trying to compile?

Comment: Actually the errors point to some other file by the name : xt1common and type_traits. I have never included these in my programs. These files seem to have complex programming inside.

Comment: There exists a folder called External Dependencies when browse through the Solution Explorer. These files come from that folder. However these are added by default when the project was created.

Comment: Try creating an empty project and typing in only the text from your post.  Also, do not use precompiled headers.

Comment: The same error occurs

Comment: Your compiler is broken then. Try to reinstall it.

Comment: Is the `iostream` header included (`#include <iostream>`)?